# Error in installing Cocoapods into project

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, calendarview

I am having an error in installing cocoapods in one of my projects directory. The error states this "[!] The dependency `CalendarView (from`..`)` is not used in any concrete target."

Here is the whole thing...

```
 MyName-MBP:~ MyName$ cd /Users/MyNamea/Documents/CalendarView- master/CalendarViewDemo 
 MyName-MBP:CalendarViewDemo MyName$ pod install
 Re-creating CocoaPods due to major version update.
 Analyzing dependencies
[!] The dependency `CalendarView (from `..`)` is not used in any     concrete target.
MyName-MBP:CalendarViewDemo MyName$
```

Answer (score 0):

First open your terminal ,and then

Write cd / your project path and hit enter button,then

Write the command- $sudo pod init and hit the enter 
button,it may takes some time

Now go to your project directory and find pod file , open the POD file and past the dependency framework that you want to use in your project. And then

Write the command:- $sudo pod install and hit enter button , it may takes some time to install. After the successful installation close the xcode project and go to your project directory where you will find workspace  open it and write all your code here. Hopefully It could help you.